# How to add a different css style in a static page in XMLUI theme dspace?

Tags: xslt, dspace

How to Add a different css style in a static page in XMLUI theme dspace? Without harming the current theme CSS.

Comment: in case it would be a static page, for example:
www.myrepository.us/xmlui/page/test

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to apply this custom CSS to your entire site, or to one particular theme?  If you have defined multiple themes, you can add custom CSS files to a specific theme in the sitemap.xmap file.

```
                   <map:transform type="IncludePageMeta">
                        <map:parameter name="stylesheet.screen" value="lib/style.css"/>
                        <map:parameter name="stylesheet.screen#2" value="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css"/>

                        <map:parameter name="javascript#1" value="lib/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"/>
                        <map:parameter name="javascript#2" value="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"/>

                        <map:parameter name="theme.path" value="{global:theme-path}"/>
                        <map:parameter name="theme.name" value="{global:theme-name}"/>
                    </map:transform>
```

[Sample sitemap.xmap CSS inclusion](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Reference/sitemap.xmap#L88-L89)

Answer (score 0):

You must add "class" and "ids" to the html components of the static page, and, at the css, set the properties with the desired values